# psql escape backslash

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to escape backslash by `\b` so I can later on process it normally.
So far I use a command that return tab separated result which coverts nulls into `\N` as well (for mysql `load into`):

```
PGPASSWORD=$PASS psql -qtAX -U $USER -h $HOST -p $PORT -d $DB -AF $'\t' -P 'null=\N'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I'm understanding your question...*

`psql` offers options for formatting its output (e.g., how it delimits columns and rows, how it presents null values, whether it includes a footer, whether it presents tuples only, whether it presents using its expanded format, etc.); *however*, I don't believe it offers options to encode, escape, or otherwise process row/field-level data, such as replacing backslashes in stored data.

To accomplish what you seem to be trying to accomplish, I believe you'd need to use a SQL function like `replace` or `regexp_replace`, or would need to post-process your output (e.g., using `sed`).

*Several loosely related thoughts:*

- *You might want to consider an alternative to `\b`, as `\b` often denotes a backspace in backslash encodings.*
- *You might want to consider an alternative to `PGPASSWORD` (and `PASS`) use, as it may be exposing your password to other users, known and otherwise (as environment variables can be extracted).*
- *`PGHOST`, `PGPORT`, `PGUSER`, etc. may be worth checking out as possible alternatives to specifying them for `psql` (not a terribly important thought, though possible interesting to you).*

P.S.  Thanks for posting your question...  Lots of great `psql` options there.

Comment: using sed like `s/\\/\\\\/g` will hurt `-P 'null=\N'`

Comment: but there is solution for that to ignore `\N` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105490/search-and-replace-backslash-except-one-thing?noredirect=1#73105647